# How to see who logged in to Community site with SSO?

Tags: lightning-community

So, what I'm trying to figure out is how to get a report of users that logged in to my community site using SSO.
I have an internal self-service community site that users from my company can log in to using SSO. However, I can't seem to find how to check who logged to the site and when. Is it possible? It seems like a very basic feature.

Thank you all in advance,
Lior.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download login history. You can export 6 months worth of history from Setup, or download using Data Loader.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333293&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Hi Jan, Thank you for your reply. I couldn't find any way of distinction between regular logins to the platform and logins in to the community page.